# How to run 2 SSH commands separately using PHP?

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to use an SSH connection through PHP to run Bash scripts.

I wrote a script to make backups and restores for a MySQL database and I am still testing to achieve this. I have encountered a problem while trying to 
run two different simple commands. My code is:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if(!($con = ssh2_connect("server.hosting.com", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {

    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "username", "password")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";




        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "cd directory " ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "mkdir directiry2" ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It still creates another directory but not inside the "directory"! 
Please help!!!

Comment: why not just `mkdir -p directory/directiry2`? You don't need to cd into a dir to make something inside it.

Comment: Thanks for that Marc B, now how can  i run something like this :

`mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3 > mydb_tables.sql`

Comment: [shameless pub] you might want to have a look at https://github.com/tivie/command

It enables you to chain shell commands and set cwd in an OOP way

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do cd the "state" is lost right after. The phpseclib docs elaborate:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir,

If you want to be able to cd to a directory and then do stuff in that directory you can chain stuff. eg. `$ssh->exec('cd directory; mkdir directiry2');`